# No recibo las notificaciones de cloud messagin

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy intentando recibir notificaciones con cloud messaging pero no recibo nada. No tengo logeo con firebase (por si es importante aclarar)
En mi cuenta en firebase tengo otra app que si recibo notificaciones sin problemas, la app que recibe las notificaciones y la que no, estan las 2 subidas al play store. Probe creando otro proyecto nuevo solo para esta app por si el problema era ese pero no... al configurar con la guia de firebase al final cuando comprueba si la app se comunica con el servidor me figura que si se comunica. Pero creo la notificacion, coloco que se enviaria a mi app obviamente pero nada... no la recibo. agrege todas las dependencias y el archivo json, tambien agrege las lineas al manifest.

Tienes razon! detallo lo que copie en el manifest

```
`<service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>`

lo que implemente en el gradle 

`    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'`

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' (tambien en la parte superior del gradle)
```

y por ultimo el gradle proyect

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Tambien agrege el archivo json que descargue en la raiz de la carpeta app.

Comment: Hola, Sebastian. Bienvenidx a SOes. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: La mejor forma que tienes para describir lo que has intentado y lo que no funciona es incluir las configuraciones que probaste y, si los hay, los logs (no sé si acá sea relevante revisar logcat, por ejemplo). En su formato actual, la pregunta sólo permite opinar y adivinar.

Comment: Hola gracias! lo que pasa es que solo coloque lo que indica la documentacion de google no se si sea muy relevante colocarlo. Saludos y gracias

Comment: Es que así, a ciegas, no sabemos siquiera si es un error tipográfico.

Comment: La pregunta importante es como envias las notificaciones y en que mètodo de tu app la recibes?

Comment: Intento enviar una notificacion simple desde cloud messagin